# Sum of a non-uniform subset

Tags: r, function, subset, subset-sum

In my project, I have bunch of information about a bus company. I separate a subset by date, so I could see the most required bus lines (which are in the "Linha" column) from a barplot.

->E.g. of subset:

> data.date[[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Q9v.png)]] is equivalent of the subset of rows that have the date "2013-03-10".

For this to be accomplished, I tried to sum all the values in the dim "Catraca"(ticket gate) in a vector for all the different "Linhas" (bus lines). And, I'm struggling hard.

This is logic I used

```
linha.sum <- with(data.date[[1]], data.date[[1]] == linha.unique, sum(data.date[[1]]$Catraca))
```

The output was some logical vector. Not the desired.

This are some pictures which might help you understand the situation

```
 View(data.date[[1]])
```

[image: Picture of the sample]

The values I want to sum are the "Catraca" of the different "Linha"

Sample of the data:

```
data.dates <- list(read.table(text = "Linha     DSaida HSaida   DChegada HChegada Sentido Catraca Embarcado
                                          3 2016-01-01  04:05 2016-01-01    04:15       0       0         0
                                          3 2016-01-01  04:23 2016-01-01    23:57       0      37         0
                                          3 2016-01-01  04:05 2016-01-01    04:15       0       0         0
                                          3 2016-01-01  04:22 2016-01-01    23:58       0      83         0
                                          3 2016-01-01  04:04 2016-01-01    04:15       0       0         0
                                          3 2016-01-01  04:23 2016-01-01    23:58       0      43         0
                                          6 2016-01-01  03:49 2016-01-01    13:41       0      82         0
                                          6 2016-01-01  13:43 2016-01-01    23:09       0      98         0
                                          7 2016-01-01  03:54 2016-01-01    14:49       0      61         0
                                          7 2016-01-01  14:51 2016-01-01    23:10       0      46         0", header = T))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to share your data.

Comment: do you want to have the sum of all `catraca`s for all dates?

Comment: @loki Exactly. All the catracas values for all the unique dates from the subset

Comment: @ycw I'm trying to solve this problem. My subset is quite big and the dput(head("subset), n = 1L) its so big that it does not fit the console

Comment: Your query asks for sum of "Catraca" based on different "Linha". `aggregate(df$Catraca, by = list(Linha = df$Linha), FUN = sum)` will provide that.

Comment: @Sagar This logic was fantastic. Can you please use it as an answer?

Comment: @theBotelho - Glad this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `data.dates` seems to be a list of data.frames (probably created by `split()`), the sums of a column within each of these data sets can acquired with `lapply`.

Here is some reproducible data:

```
data.dates <- list(data.frame(
  Linha = c(3,3,1201,1201), 
  Catraca = c(0,37,2,22)
))
```

### With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(data.dates, function(x) {
         x %>% group_by(Linha) %>% summarize(catSum = sum(Catraca))
})
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#    Linha         catSum
#    <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1     3             37
# 2  1201             24
```

This will then add a column to each data.frame within the list containing the sum per each group (by date and linha)

### with base `R`

From @Sagars comment you could also use `aggregate` in `lapply`:

```
lapply(data.dates, function(x) {
  aggregate(x$Catraca, by = list(Linha = x$Linha), FUN = sum)
})
# [[1]]
#   Linha  x
# 1     3 37
# 2  1201 24
```

#### Benchmarking

In fact, `microbenchmark()` reveals, that the base solution (as often) is faster in this case. However, this is only tested with the small subset given in OP.

```
# Unit: microseconds
#   expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#  dplyr 1803.553 1878.499 1994.4945 1918.8880 2016.8730 6495.747   100   b
#   base  481.535  513.818  543.4041  538.1365  560.4635  803.222   100  a
```

Comment: Sorry, I miss spelled the comment from above. 
@loki All the catracas values for all the "Linhas" from the subset of different dates (the subset of different dates are the lists of data.date, thus data.date[[1]] is the first subset with only date X)

Comment: Look the double `[[` indicate that you have some kind of list. Therefore, if you want to get the sums for all the "subsets", i.e. list entries, you have to apply a function on all the list elements (aka "subsets"). See `?lapply` for more information about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your query asks for sum of "Catraca" based on different "Linha".

`aggregate(df$Catraca, by = list(Linha = df$Linha), FUN = sum)`

will provide that.